# CSS grid with fixed column size that adds extra columns to fill width of container

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid that varies in width and number of results.

Each cell in the grid is 200x200 px.

As the grid expands, I want the column width to remain fixed and for new columns to be added in. You could imagine the grid initially having 3 columns, and when the user expands the window, a fourth column is added in to use the new whitespace.

This grid is rendering a set of search results.

1. So I need to be able to vary the number of rows depending on number of results.
2. I need to be able to have the columns fill up the horizontal space dynamically.
3. I need results to first fill up each row before moving to the next row.

Here is what I've been trying, but it is not currently working as it only renders a single column (CSS in JS, but it's just CSS):

```
  ResultsGrid: {
    display: grid,
    gridAutoRows: 280px,
    gridAutoColumns: 280px,
    gap: 20px,
    gridAutoFlow: row-dense,
  }

  Result: {
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA,
  }
```

Desired Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my implementation:

The `auto-fit` argument with `repeat` CSS function

```css
.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: orange;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  gap: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">html</div>
  <div class="grid-item">html</div>
  <div class="grid-item">html</div>
  <div class="grid-item">html</div>
  <div class="grid-item">html</div>
  <div class="grid-item">html</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem before, here is what you need:

```
ResultsGrid {
  display: grid;
  gridTemplateColumns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  gridAutoRows: 10rem;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What language is that?